# Invalid type: StepsAndWorkitems

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process

Please help me with this. In the second for loop this error is coming

```
     Map<Id,ProcessInstance> processinstence = New Map<Id,ProcessInstance>([SELECT Id, Status, (SELECT ID, ProcessNodeId,  
                         StepStatus,Comments,TargetObjectId,ActorId,CreatedById,IsDeleted,IsPending  
                         ,OriginalActorId,ProcessInstanceId,RemindersSent,CreatedDate, Actor.Name,  
                         OriginalActor.Name , ProcessNode.Name FROM StepsAndWorkitems)   
                   FROM ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId =:'a002v0000441VOX' order by CreatedDate DESC]); 

     for(ProcessInstance pr :  processinstence.values()){
         For(StepsAndWorkitems  str : pr.StepsAndWorkitems) {
            // wrappercls.add(New WrapperController(pr.Status,str.Comments,str.Comments));
         }
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

`StepsAndWorkitems` is not a type, it is a child relationship name for `ProcessInstanceHistory`, so type should be `ProcessInstanceHistory` and not `StepsAndWorkitems`.

Excerpt from the salesforce documentation

> The nested query references StepsAndWorkitems, which is the child
>   relationshipName for ProcessInstanceHistory in the ProcessInstance
>   object.

You can refer documentation of [ProcessInstanceHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstancehistory.htm) for further information on this topic.

Replace `StepsAndWorkitems` with `ProcessInstanceHistory`, so your code should be

```
Map<Id,ProcessInstance> processinstence = New Map<Id,ProcessInstance>([SELECT Id, Status, (SELECT ID, ProcessNodeId,  
                         StepStatus,Comments,TargetObjectId,ActorId,CreatedById,IsDeleted,IsPending  
                         ,OriginalActorId,ProcessInstanceId,RemindersSent,CreatedDate, Actor.Name,  
                         OriginalActor.Name , ProcessNode.Name FROM StepsAndWorkitems)   
                   FROM ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId =:'a002v0000441VOX' order by CreatedDate DESC]); 

for(ProcessInstance pr :  processinstence.values()){
    for(ProcessInstanceHistory  str : pr.StepsAndWorkitems) {
        // wrappercls.add(New WrapperController(pr.Status,str.Comments,str.Comments));
    }
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vijay ganji